# Accessing Element inside Listview gives java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

I'm trying loop through `Listview` to get `EditText` values.

This is my code for getting `Textview` values :

```
View list_v = null;
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);

    ArrayList<String> listitems = new ArrayList<String>();
    EditText et;

    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
        list_v = listView.getChildAt(i);

        et = (EditText) list_v.findViewById(R.id.editText_a);
        listitems.add(et.getText().toString());

    }
```

and my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     >

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/code"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp" 
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/kcode_lbl"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     >
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_a"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:layout_weight="1" >        
        </EditText>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText_lbl"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_value"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_lbl"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

my main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <AutoCompleteTextView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/code_txt"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" 
        android:digits="0123456789" 
        android:inputType="number"
        android:focusable="true">
        <requestFocus />
        </AutoCompleteTextView>

</LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Problem is when I run the code it gives `java.lang.NullPointerException`  on this line of code:

```
list_v.findViewById(R.id.editText_a)
```

Should I iterate through `LinearLayout` too ?

Comment: Is it your custom xml file ?? Have you inflated it ??

Comment: this is my listview xml and im using it in my only activity.
in activity im using     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
-->main is the place that i put my listview

Comment: So where is listview in that file?? You can access this view only when you have inflated them in to custom adapter or list adapter class.

Comment: ive updated my question with main.xml

Comment: First change this `listView.getCount();` to `listView.getChildCount();` and access your `list_v`  in for loop or make it global and remove `null` from it.

Comment: thank you that was the problem. listView.getChildCount() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        list_v = listView.getChildAt(i);

        et = (EditText) list_v.findViewById(R.id.editText_a);
        listitems.add(et.getText().toString());

    }
```

Replace `getCount()` with `getChildCount()`